# Why do I get different row orderings when I run my query with sp_executesql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that puts a row with a certain ID before all other rows. Here is an example of how it can be used to put location 12007 before the rest:

```
SELECT 12007 as location_id
UNION
SELECT  location_id
FROM locations
WHERE location_id <> 12007;
```

I have tried to execute this query using sp_executesql and a query parameter:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT @LocationID as location_id
UNION
SELECT  location_id
FROM locations
WHERE location_id <> @LocationID;',N'@LocationID nvarchar(5)',@LocationID=N'12007'
```

This, however, does not result in location 12007 coming before the rest. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL result sets are *unordered* unless you explicitly define the ordering.

If you want a specific ordering, use `order by`:

```
SELECT location_id
FROM ((SELECT 12007 as location_id
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT location_id
       FROM locations
       WHERE location_id <> 12007
      )
     ) l
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN location_id = 12007 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END);
```

Note the use of `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.  This does not incur the overhead of removing duplicates.

If you know 12007 is in the list of locations, then a simpler method is:

```
SELECT location_id
FROM locations l
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN location_id = 12007 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END);
```

Comment: The simpler method has the side effect of causing the rest of the locations to start at current location + 1, instead of from 0.

Comment: @jtm . . . No, they are in an arbitrary order.  If you want them in a particular order, say by `location_id`, then add that as a *second* key in the `order by`.